# MySQLdb : double quotes passed to the query

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm getting mad with MySQLdb ! I'm following exactly the official doc but I have an error with the code :

```
DB_TABLE = "test"
cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM " + DB_TABLE)
print "***"
cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM %s" , (DB_TABLE,))
```

I get the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dbscript.py", line 49, in <module>
    cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM %s" , (DB_TABLE,))
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test'' at line 1")
```

Obviously there is a problem with some quotes. My command seems to send a line like this to MySQL :

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM ''test''
```

How can I change the double quote by a single one ?

I'v tried the followings :

```
DB_TABLE = 'test'
cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM %s" , [DB_TABLE])
cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM %s" , ("test",))
```

But nothing works :(

Comment: Create a string of the entire SQL and print it before executing. Also -- is it actually `test` or did you change that to hide the table name from us? If the table name is something like `desc` then it's a reserved keyword and will error out

Comment: 'test' is a real table and I was looking for a way beside concatenation, which works fine (cf 1st line)

Comment: @user777466 concatenation is fine in this case.

Comment: OK, but in which case is concatenation not ok ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM %s" , ("test",))
```

and in similar statements, the `cursor.execute` will substitute SQL parameters into %s.

What you need is something like this

```
sql = "SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM %s" % ("test", )
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Using % formatting instead of , parameters opens up SQL injection possibility.  if test were entered by a user as "bob; drop database something;" you'll execute both statements.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot parameterized table name, so you have to sanitize it yourself and use string substitution in the query instead.

To **sanitize** a table name in a query with multiple parameters:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE columnName = %s" % (tableName,'%s')
print(query)
```

At this point, query will display as:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columName = %s
```

Once you've constructed your cursor, use the parameterized condition:

```
cursor.execute(query,(columnValue,))
```

The actual query that mySQL will read in then is:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnName = columnValue
```

If you try to pass in a table name without sanitizing it, you'll get a syntax error.